# setState from input on change - can't delete from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `input`:

```
 <input type="text" value={this.state.current} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

`handleChange()` method:

```
handleChange(e) {
  let val = parseInt(e.target.value); 
  if (val) {
    this.set(val);
  }
}
```

and `set()` method (simple set number between 1 and 5 to the state):

```
set(val = 1) {
  if (val < 1) {
    val = 1;
  }
  if (val > 5) {
    val = 5;
  }
  this.setState({ current: val });
}
```

My problem is: when i want to change value in input, i can't delete number from it. I think it is auto filled from state imediatly after I delete number. Where is the problem in my code?

exmaple on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4sc3p2ny/

Comment: `set(val = 1)` is only for init. Even if i remove it (`set(val)`) i still can't delete numbers from input.

Comment: If you will remove set(val) it will not allow you to change as it shows value mapped to `current` , which will not change if you will remove `set(val)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are trying completely remove value from input, `e.target.value` returns `''` in this case `parseInt(e.target.value)` returns `NaN`, because `parseInt('')` returns `NaN`., you need check it and set `current` as empty string

```
 handleChange(e) {
   let val = parseInt(e.target.value);

   if (isNaN(val)) {
     this.setState({ current: '' });
   } else {
     if (val < 1) {
       val = 1;
     }

     if (val) {
       this.set(val);
     }
   }
 }
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/4sc3p2ny/3/)

Answer (score -2):

Remove `value={this.state.current}` from the `input` element

Comment: I think he wants to make it a controlled component, there's just an issue with how he's trying to do it.